# Read consistency on page split

Tags: sql-server, database

For simplicity, lets suppose we have some non-leaf page A where key is int.
We want to find key 4812 and at this point we have entries 2311 and 5974.
So, current thread acquires a shared latch for that page and calculates that it needs leaf page B (for data between 2311 and 5974).

At the same time, some other thread is inserting on page B, previously acquiring exclusive latch on it.
Because of insert, it has to split page on entry 3742 and create new Page C with upper half of data.

First thread has finished reading and releases the latch on Page A.
If it tries to find key 4812 on Page B (after exclusive latch is released) it won't find it, because it was moved to Page C during page split.

If I understand correctly, latch is implemented with spinlock and it should be short lived.
In order to prevent this kind of problem, writer thread would have to keep latches on all traversed non-leaf pages, which would be extremely inefficient.

I have basically 2 questions:

1. Is latch on page level only or it can be on row level also? I couldn't find information about that. If that was the case, then impact wouldn't be that big, but it would still be wasteful when there are no page splits (and that's mostly the case).
2. Is there some other mechanism to cover this?

My question is about Sql Server because I'm familiar with its internals, but this should apply to mostly any other database.

Comment: If you go through your logic step by step you find out - it is broken. See, you have thread B ackquiring an exclusive latch, but you have a latch already in place for the split. T3rd paragraph has a latch, so 2nd paragraph could not have gotten an EXCLUSIVE latch.

Comment: @TomTom Thread 2 has exclusive latch on Page B because it came there before Thread 1. At the time of acquiring the latch, Thread 2 didn't have to acquire exclusive latch on non-leaf page also. After Thread 1 finds the page number of leaf page it can release shared latch. Because Thread 2 is currently splitting page, Thread 1 can't proceed any further, but Thread 2 can now take exclusive latch on Page A and insert new entry. I'm not saying that my logic isn't broken, but I just can't seem to understand how this is correctly handled.

Comment: Then Thread 1 can not have a shared latch at the same time.

Comment: Let's use slightly clearer identifiers. Reader is R, writer is W, P for the parent page of the leaves, L1 for the leaf page that needs to be split, and L2 for the newly created leaf page. For W to split L1 into L1 and L2, W has to acquire a lock on P in addition to L1, because P will need to be changed. If R was first and is still reading P, then W has to wait. If W  was first and is already writing to L1 and L2, then W already had the lock on P, so R has to wait.

Comment: In answer to your listed question: latches don't happen at the row level. But page splits will require locks anyway, not just latches (perhaps better said, latches are locks, but locks aren't latches)

Comment: @TomTom So, Thread 2 would have to keep exclusive latch on all traversed pages?
Timing would be like this:
T2: acquire shared latch on Page A
T2: read Page A
T2: release latch on Page A
T1:acquire shared latch on Page A
T2:acquire exclusive latch on Page B
T1:read Page A
T1:release shared latch
T2:...
If T2 woudn't keep exclusive latch on Page A whole time, this would create problem I previously mentioned. But, if that is the case, that would be really inefficient.

Comment: @TomTom So basically the only way to keep consistency is to acquire and keep exclusive latch on whole traverse path although thread probably won't have to write anything on them (except for page split). That could be really inefficient because it would keep exclusive lock on root page preventing all readers to proceed until insert has finished.

Comment: @TomTom In other solution, if W acquires latch for P only after he finds out that it needs to split, then W could take exclusive latch immediately after R releases shared latch.

Comment: Pretty much. YOu msut make sure that nothing else happens while you do changes. This is as much an art as it is a trade - keep locks as small as possible but as large as necessary.

Comment: I don't know the exact algorithm, but conceptually, no, it doesn't have to lock every page in the traversal path. Consider the following algorithm for the splitter: Traverse the index down to the leaves, finding the values you want, taking shared locks only. Discover that you need to split the pages. Find which pages of the path need to  be changed (this is not necessarily *all* of them. Usually it will be the leaves and one parent). Acquire exclusive locks on those index pages, and the leaf pages, that actually need to change. not necessarily all from the root down. Also, I am not @TomTom :D

Comment: R doesn't have to release its lock on P before acquiring its lock on L1. It could take the L1 lock and *then* release P.

Comment: @allmuhran I know, you simplified problem a bit, so I used your terminology for TomTom. Regarding your comment, you could be onto something. If W would try to acquire latch on P before L1 (because it know that it has to split) that would prevent anomaly. W would have to wait for R to release P. At that time W is holding shared latch on L1, so R could proceed without problems. Of course, there are many edge cases that would have to be covered, but it would be more performant solution.

Comment: Basically they both have to do their operations in the same order (in terms of tree order), otherwise a deadlock can occur. So, given `+` as take, `^` as escalate, `-` as release, `s` as shared, `x` as exclusive, we have: `R = +sP +sL1 -sP -sL1`, and `W = +sP +sL1 ^xP ^xL1 -xP -xL1`

Comment: @allmhuran I agree